# Move a color shade down in color picker programatically?

Tags: javascript

I have an input box where the user can set the color of an object. I want to add a check box that the user clicks that says 'make 3D' which adds a text-shadow effect to the object to give it a 3D appearance. The 3D effect needs a lighter shade of the base color to make it look correct. If I want to use the base color as a start, and programatically move one shade lighter for the first text shadow, two shades lighter for the second shadow etc. is that possible?

They can input any color they want, but the text-shadow should use that input and move one or two shades lighter at a time.

**HTML**

```
<p>Object Color:<input type="text" class="object_color" value="FF8000" id="object_color"></p>
```

---

**CSS to add to object**

```
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #one-shade-lighter-than-FF8000,
               0 2px 0 #one-shade-lighter-than-FF8000,
               0 3px 0 #two-shades-lighter-than-FF8000,
               0 4px 0 #two-shades-lighter-than-FF8000,
               0 5px 0 #three-shades-lighter-than-FF8000,
               0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
               0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
               0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
               0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
               0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15)
```

I guess ultimately can we subtract colors from one another to move to a new color like

```
var textShadow = rgb(156, 87, 135) - rgb(2, 4, 18)
```

Comment: have you considered using sass? http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method

Comment: Mabe think of using a library...Tiny Color is great ... https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor

Comment: Im using jscolor for the color picker, Ill take a look at tiny color

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue with a peice of javascript code that I came accross online.

The script takes in a hex value, converts it to RGB then darkens or lightens the color depending on your sepcifications, and returns the lightened or darkened color. It works quite a charm for what I need it to do.

```
function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {
// validate hex string
hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
if (hex.length < 6) {
    hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
}
lum = lum || 0;
// convert to decimal and change luminosity
var rgb = "#", c, i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
    c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
    rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
}
return rgb;
```

}

returns

```
ColorLuminance("#69c", 0);      // returns "#6699cc"
ColorLuminance("6699CC", 0.2);  // "#7ab8f5" - 20% lighter
ColorLuminance("69C", -0.5);    // "#334d66" - 50% darker
ColorLuminance("000", 1);       // "#000000" - true black cannot be made lighter!`
```

I got it off the site: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/

for any one that may need it as a reference moving forward.